# Integrate $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{4\cos^2(t)+9\sin^2(t)}\mathrm{d}t$ with complex functions or Fourier transformations.

Tags: complex-numbers, fourier-transform, complex-integration

> What is the value of the following integral:
> $$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{4\cos^2(t)+9\sin^2(t)}\mathrm{d}t$$
> $\frac\pi9$ ; $\frac\pi6$ ; $\frac\pi3$ ; $\frac\pi2$ or $\frac\pi4$?

a full solution for this problem would be much appreciated

Comment: Rather than an external link or an image, you can use MathJax to insert the integral into your question.

Answer (score 2):

Integrate with Fourier series as follows

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{4\cos^2 t+9\sin^2 t}{d}t
=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{2}{13-5\cos 2t} {d}t\\
=\int_0^{2\pi}\left( \frac16 + \frac13\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{5^n} \cos (2n t) \right)dt
=\frac\pi3
$$

Comment: We just looked at an integral like this (after your first step) a few minutes ago!:   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4000605/how-can-i-derive-the-integral-like-this-one/4000616#4000616

Comment: Anyway "plus one"

Comment: thank you firstly, do you think there could be a way where we substitute cos(2t) with z of some sort then use the residue to calculate the integral?

Comment: @FoadHijab - You could. Then, refer to the link in the comment above

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using differentiation under integral sign. Consider a more general integral, namely:

\begin{align*}
I_1(\alpha,\beta) & = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{\alpha \cos^2x+\beta \sin^2x} \\
                  & = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\sec^2x}{\alpha + \beta \tan^2x} \,\mathrm{d}x\\
                  & = \frac{1}{\beta} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}\right)^2 + \tan^2 (x)}\; \mathrm{d}(\tan x)\,\\
& = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha \beta}} \left[ \left(\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\beta}{\alpha}}\tan (x)\right)\right) \right]_0^{2\pi} = \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{\alpha\beta}}
\end{align*}