# How can I derive the integral like this one?

Tags: integration

I have a problem with integral like this one:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\text{d}x}{\cos x+a}$$

when $a$ is from $1$ to $+\infty$.

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: The image is itself from Integral Calculator. I doubt if it's not solved there.

Comment: Tried [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B1%2F%28a%2BCos%5Bx%5D%29%5D)?

Comment: @gt6989b, well yes.  You can also give "Alpha" a definite integral.

Comment: @gt6989b, In *Mathematica* it is `Assuming[a>1,Integrate[1/(a+Cos[x]),{x,0,2*Pi}]]`.  Doesn't seem that WolframAlpha can handle this syntax.  Any ideas how to get it to evaluate this?

Comment: Doesn't cost much to say that the integral is asymptotic to $\frac{2\pi}a$.

Comment: Do not deface your posts.

Answer (score 2):

The constant $a$ must be strictly greater than $1.$

In that case, let $z=e^{i x}$ and $\cos x = \frac{1}{2}( e^{i x}+e^{-i x}) = \frac{1}{2} (z+1/z)$, etc.

After evaluating the integral by computing the residue at the pole inside the contour, you should obtain:
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dx}{a+\cos x} = \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Another approach writes $2\int_0^\pi\frac{dx}{\cos x+a}$ with $t=\tan\tfrac{x}{2}=\sqrt{\tfrac{a+1}{a-1}}\tan y$ as$$\int_0^\infty\frac{4dt}{a+1+(a-1)t^2}=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{4dy}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

A common method for integrals of this form is to use the [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution) which transforms the integral as so:
$$t=\tan(x/2)$$
$$\cos x=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$
$$dx=\frac{2}{1+t^2}dt$$
you may also want to consider changing your domain

Answer (score 0):

> $$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\text{d}x}{a + \cos(x)}$$

Stepping into the complex plane:

$$z = e^{ix} ~~~~~~~ \cos(x) \to \frac{1}{2}\left(z + \frac{1}{z}\right) ~~~~~~~ \text{d}x = \frac{\text{d}z}{iz}$$

The integral becomes

$$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{\text{d}z}{iz\left(a + \frac{1}{2}\left(z + \frac{1}{z}\right)\right)}$$

Now we arrange it into

$$ \frac{2}{i} \int_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{z^2 + 2az + 1} 
= \frac{2}{i} \int_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)}$$

where the circle $|z|=1$ is parametrized counterclockwise and
\begin{align*} z_1 = -a - \sqrt{a^2-1}  && z_2 = -a + \sqrt{a^2-1}.
\end{align*}

are the poles of the integrand function.

Clearly $z_1 < -a < -1$, so $z_1$ is outside of the unit circle. As for $z_2$, it is convenient to notice that
\begin{align*}
z_1 z_2 = 1. 
\end{align*}
Thus, since $z_1$ is outside the unit circle, its inverse $z_2$ is inside the unit circle. So, applying the residue theorem, we have

\begin{align*}
\frac{2}{i} \int_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)}
&= \frac{2}{i} \ 2 \pi i \ \mathrm{Res}\left( \frac{1}{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)}, z_2\right) \\
&= 4 \pi \frac{1}{z_2 - z_1} \\
&= 4 \pi \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{a^2 -1}} \\
&= \boxed{\frac{2 \pi}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}}
\end{align*}